# Ao registrar minha classe dá pau com o método OnAppearing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou a tempos tentando fazer notificação com xamarin e o plugin Xam.Plugin.PushNotification. O problema está quando eu registro o plugin. Ele não funciona, no momento em que o método ***AtualizaDADOS()*** é chamado. Em realidade o que eu quero é o seguinte: Sempre que uma campo em meu BD for atualizado(**FlagLiberacao**) passar de 0 para 1, o usuário que tem o App vai receber uma informação. Não sei se para isso eu necessito realmente de uma servidor, como o **firebase** ou **azure** para enviar essas **informações/notificações**. Meus código abaixo:
Construtor da mainpage

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                dataService = new DataService();
                AtualizaDados();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string erro = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

O método OnAppearing

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            try
            {
                lblTipoVenda.Text = "Tipo de Venda:";
                lblVencimento.Text = "Vencimento:";
                lblJuros.Text = "Juros:";
                lblEntrada.Text = "Entrada:";
                lblAcrescimo.Text = "Acréscimo:";
                lblDesconto.Text = "Desconto:";
                btnItens.IsEnabled = false;

                AtualizaDados();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string erro = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

O método AtualizaDados

```
private async void AtualizaDados()
        {
            try
            {
                lib = await dataService.GetLiberaAsync();
                listaLibera.ItemsSource = lib.OrderBy(item => item.Cliente).ToList();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string erro = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

A classe CrossNotificationListener criada no projeto android

```
public class CrossPushNotificationListener : IPushNotificationListener
    {
        public CrossPushNotificationListener()
        {
        }

        public void OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public bool ShouldShowNotification()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

No forum do Xamarin, o autor do plugin, disse-me para eu inicializar fora do mainActivity, mas como eu faço isso, uma classe de inicialização. Veja o que ele disse:

> It seems you are initializing in the MainActivity instead of an
>   Application class, if you want it to work when closed then should
>   initialize there instead. Anyways If you are using firebase for both
>   iOS and Android I will recommend you use:

Eu gostaria de entender o que significa esse registro, para poder entender porque ele não aceita trabalhar junto com o serviço e outras coisas, como listview e etc..

Answer (score 0):

Olá esse plugin foi descontinuado: https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/blob/master/PushNotification/README.md

Para notificação eu uso https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PushNotificationPlugin.

E se vc quer notificar sempre q seu campo FlagLiberacao passar de 0 para 1, quando isso ocorrer vc deve dá um post pro Firebase.

Segue a documentação do Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/