# O que realmente é PushNotification?

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

Fiquei na dúvida agora sobre *PushNotification* e se realmente é o que eu quero. Para resolver o meu problema eu preciso de *PushNotification*? Veja só, o que eu quero é isso: Quando o usuário(vendedor) alterar a flag do banco de dados, isso indica que esse vendedor está solicitando um desconto maior que o que ele pode conceder. Dessa forma, quem tem esse poder não fica nas lojas, mas sim na matriz e essas pessoas, irão receber em seus *smartphone* informação para abrir o App e Aprovar/Negar esse desconto. Posso dizer que isso é por *PushNotification* ou há outra forma de fazê-lo?

Comment: Sim, é por aí mesmo o conceito de _push notification_. A informação é empurrada para o app, o app não puxa ela

Comment: Estou com muita dificuldade para implementar. Não está funcionando comigo e já abri outro post sobre o assunto. Fiquei na dúvida e vim aqui perguntar se o que eu estou querendo é realmente PushNotification ou se há outro jeito de se fazer, @JeffersonQuesado.

Comment: Perdão pelas palavras, mas é realmente um estorvo fazer funcionar um _push notification_. Você normalmente está à mercê de algum framework de terceiros, como o Firebase que está descrito na resposta do @acklay

Answer (score 8):

*[Push](https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR#en/pt/push)* traduzida do inglês, significa empurrar, impulsionar[...]. Já *[Notification](https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR#en/pt/notification)*, é notificação, comunicação, aviso[...]. Unindo as duas palavras, temos como exemplo "impulsionar notificação". O objetivo principal do *Push Notification* é encurtar o caminho entre o emissor e o receptor

O intuito não é trafegar uma grande massa de dados, e sim enviar mensagens simples, para, por exemplo, avisar que há um novo dado a ser baixado do servidor, ou mostrar algum tipo de promoção de loja, atualização de sistema, etc.

De acordo com uma pesquisa feita pela [Urban Airship](https://www.urbanairship.com/), o uso diário de um aplicativo aumenta cerca de até 540% com o envio dessas notificações.

Hoje em dia usar o Push Notification ficou muito mais fácil usando o [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br). Veja mais [detalhes na documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br). Aqui também na [documentação do Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/firebase-cloud-messaging/) também tem um *quickstart* explicando e explicando como funciona o FCM.

É possível criar uma solução para seu problema através tanto do *Push Notification* quanto *[Pull Notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology)*<sup>en</sup>. A diferença é que *Pull* verifica se no servidor há alguma atualização, enquanto o *Push* notificará o usuário quando houver alguma atualização. Para seu caso talvez, digo talvez, a maneira mais viável seria usando o *Push Notification*, pois evitará de criar serviço para verificação de atualização tempos em tempos. A maneira mais clara de usar o *Pull Notification* é quando você armazena algum tipo de dado no *smartphone*, digo no lado cliente, no qual, através de uma determinada análise dos dados locais, você faz uma requisição ao servidor de maneira direcionada a esse cliente.

Comment: Nota: por o Firebase para funcionar o FCM em iOS a primeira vez é um estorvo.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado o problema nem é a codificação, mas sim o sistema burocrático e fechado da Apple. Hoje em dia está mais sussa.

Comment: Em realidade abri um post sobre o assunto do Firebase que comigo não está funcionando, mas isso é outro post. Nesse aqui, só quero saber se o que eu desejo e realmente Push ou Pull, conforme explicou o colega ramaral. Vou ler o link sugerido por ele e tentar entender esse assunto.

Comment: @pnet complementei a resposta. Vou dar uma olhada na sua outra pergunta para ver o que posso te ajudar. xD Boa sorte ai.

Answer (score 6):

*Push Notification* é um sistema de envio de informação para um cliente sem que este explicitamente a tenha pedido.

Ao contrário das *Pull notifications*, em que o cliente tem de solicitar a informação ao servidor, as *Push Notification* têm origem no servidor e são enviadas para os clientes sem a sua solicitação.

Como analogia, para entender melhor a diferença entre as duas, um sms é uma *Push Notification* e um email é uma *Pull notifications*.

Para informação mais completa, nomeadamente em como funcionam de forma geral, veja: [Push Notifications Explained](https://www.urbanairship.com/push-notifications-explained).

Comment: Excelente resposta. Ótimo contra-ponto com as notificações puxadas/requisitadas

Comment: ramaral, eu estou totalmente perdido no que concerne este tipo de coisa. O que eu realmente quero é fazer com que meu cliente receba a informação, de que existe um desconto para conceder ou negar. Achei que este tipo de notificação fosse por push, mas como vc está me dizendo e respeito sua opinião, no meu caso seria um **Pull Notification?**

Comment: @pnet Não, se eu entendi bem, neste caso seria uma *Push Notification*

Comment: @ramaral, meu negócio é assim: Vendedor pede(altera flag de 0 para 1) um desconto que ele não pode conceder, apenas gerentes que não estão na lojas. Esses gerentes uns 7 ou 8, vão receber em seus smarts. Isso é **push notification?**. E como meu serviço vai se comunicar com o servidor de mensagens(Cloud Messaging)? Essa é minha dúvida e acho que terei de abrir outro post para entender isso, caso o que eu quero seja um **Push** realmente.

Comment: @pnet, isso é uma *Push Notification*. Se pretende saber como implementar faça outra pergunta. Para que a pergunta não seja "ampla" seria melhor você tentar implementar primeiro. Recorra à documentação do serviço que quer utilizar.

Comment: @ramaral, já inclusive abri um post sobre o assunto sim. Aqui já está respondido. Vou tentar agora resolver meu problema com a implementação aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240088/ao-registrar-minha-classe-d%C3%A1-pau-com-o-m%C3%A9todo-onappearing